# Create Bootable Ubuntu/Windows USB to run on OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, installation

I am trying to install a couple operating systems in partitions on my MacBook Pro.  I have an 80 GB SSD with the Mac OS on it, along with a 750 GB HDD in the SuperDrive slot.  The 750 is divided into a few partitions, a couple dedicated for other OS's.  I have rEFInd installed and working.

I have followed [Ubuntu's instructions for creating a bootable USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx), all to no avail, it still will not show up in either rEFInd or when the option key is pressed upon startup.  Am I missing something?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

NOTE:  I do **not** want to virtualize (VBox, Parallels, etc.).  Ultimately, I would like to be able to "share" these partitions with VirtualBox, but that's a whole other project...